# using jquery ui slider with react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to integrate jquery ui slider with react:

```
componentDidMount: ->
  $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.slider)).slider
    value: @props.value
    min: @props.min
    max: @props.max
    step: @props.step
    slide: @handleSlide
```

Displaying the slider and handling the slide callback works fine, however I cannot update the slider from the component:

```
  slider = $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.slider)).slider
  slider("value", 123)
```

This always fails with "Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function" inside jquery ui's "widget.js". Executing `$("div.slider").slider("value", 123)` in the javascript console and in the component works fine.

But how can I get it working without having to use a css selector and use the react ref?

Answer (score 0):

Seems I have to use a different jquery ui api call to get the slider instance:

```
componentDidMount: ->
  el = $(React.findDOMNode(@refs.slider)).slider
    value: @props.value
    min: @props.min
    max: @props.max
    step: @props.step
    slide: @handleSlide
  @setState(slider: el.data("ui-slider"))
```

Later on I can then use:

```
@state.slider.value(123)
```